# How to enable the glow on synthwave 84 vscode theme on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

Synthwave 84 theme is a popular theme for vscode . But, i can't activate the glow effect of the theme . It is showing i need to run vs code as admin privilage , and i am not capable of doing that . need help !

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run vscode with Admin privilege for enabling glow on ***SynthWave 84***.

Follow these steps :

1. `sudo chown -R <user> <path_to_your_vscode_installation_directory>`
2. Hit follwing in terminal :
   To check the current user on your machine - `whoami` 
   for e.g. john
3. You can find path of vscode directory using following command : 
   `whereis code`
   e.g. in my case path is : ****/usr/share/code****
4. Now run : 
   `sudo chown -R john /usr/share/code` 
   This will run vscode with admin privilege
5. Now try activating the glow : 
   Hit ***ctrl + shift + P*** or ***cmd + shift + P*** 
   Type **Neon**,
   click the first result to activate.
   6.After reset owner back to ***root*** 
   `sudo chown -R root /usr/share/code`

Comment: For Manjaro (and most probably Arch) users, it is located under the `/usr/lib/code` folder in case you can't find it in `/usr/share/code`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use these commands:

$ sudo chown -R $(whoami)

means the path to VSCode installation, most likely you have it in here /usr/share/code.

then run the extention custom css and js, restart VSCode.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the owner of code installation files folder into the current user

most likely you can find that folder in /usr/share, to ensure try the command:

```
which code
```

this will output a path to the installation dir of code

then apply this command :

```
sudo chown -R <current_user> <installation_path>
```

which is in my case: sudo chown -R sayan /usr/share/code

After that you can apply the Neon Dreams set up in code and then run this command again to set the owner back to the root:

```
sudo chown -R root <installation_path>
```

which is in my case: sudo chown -R root /usr/share/code